# How can I get RSSI value from bluetooth communication using RFCOMM

Tags: c, bluez, rssi

I can't find code that can get Rssi value using RFCOMM with c code. 
I want to get rssi value between 2 raspberry pi 3+.

I try to find example about that (https://github.com/jtbonhomme/bbtooth/blob/master/rssi.c) but it doesn't work and i get 'Error connecting, Connection Refused'.

''

Comment: Did you try and follow this example: https://scribles.net/creating-ibeacon-using-bluez-example-code-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Which version of BlueZ are you using?